# Winforms: How to query a database with a sql function using SqlCommand?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, winforms

I have a method which takes a single string parameter (ID).

I want to use `SqlCommand` to return a `DataTable` of results from a query. I'm trying to call a table function from my database (Sql Server) in the query and pass in my ID parameter. The contents of this `DataTable` will then populate a Combobox. Here's what I have so far...

```
 public string populateCompanyTransSellingEntityLookUp(string BlockId)
    {
        string _sql = "";  

        SqlCommand _comm = new SqlCommand();
        _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@block_id", BlockId);
        _comm.CommandText = "SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fnGetBlockCompanyWIList(@block_id) ORDER BY [name]; ";
        _comm.Connection = _conn;
        _comm.CommandTimeout = _command_timeout;

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            SqlDataReader myReader = _comm.ExecuteReader();
            dt.Load(myReader);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {

            throw;
        }

        Combo.DataSource = dt;
        return _sql;                
    }
```

But i'm getting a error, "Must declare scalar variable '@block_id'". why?

Comment: I can not understand where is the problem.

Comment: _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@block_id", BlockId);_comm.CommandText = "SELECT [company_int_name] FROM dbo.fnGetBlockCompanyWIList(@block_id) ORDER BY [company_int_name]; ";

Comment: There's no question here

Comment: What exactly is wrong? Do you get an exception? Is the result set empty? Nobody can help you if you don't ask a question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have an extra bracket here, you should remove it:

```
 _comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("(@block_id", BlockId);
                               ^^^
```

And perhaps it doesn't matter but give value to your parameter after you set the `CommandText`:

```
_comm.CommandText = "SELECT [name] FROM dbo.fnGetBlockCompanyWIList(@block_id) ORDER BY [name]; ";
_comm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@block_id", BlockId);
```

Comment: how about `_comm.Connection = _conn;`, can it be placed after `_comm.CommandText`?

Comment: @V-SHY yes,it shouldn't matter.they are different properties.The important thing is setting the `Connection` property before try to execute the command.